# Visual 2015 Compiling DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, g++

I'm creating DLL that should work as module (runtime loading)
It works on linux/windows with dlopen etc..
It looks like:

.cpp

```
std::string pomnoz(std::string &s, std::string &ds)
{
    std::cout << s << "   " << ds << std::endl;
    return s.append(ds);
}
```

.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
    std::string pomnoz(std::string &s, std::string &ds);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

The problem is when I compile it with g++ it generates ~480kb .DLL that works without problem on windows/linux (I'm passing 2 strings and it returns it).
But I cant use g++ because of c14 that I use further in library.
On windows I'm using VS2015, it creates 65kb .DLL that not work(it loads but returning null instead of funcptr).
I'll tried to remove `#ifdef __cplusplus`
But nothing is changing.

Where is problem? I'll should switch something in build options?

Comment: the problem is that you need to use same std::string implementation between various modules in your program. in particular, if the host program was compiled with g++ then you should compile your dll with g++. Or you can use plain C strings instead of c++ std::string

Comment: Doesn't matter with void () is the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing dllexport next to the `pomnoz` function:

```
__declspec(dllexport) std::string pomnoz(std::string &s, std::string &ds);
```

Then in your application you can dynamically load the dll and retrieve the address to the exported function:

```
HMODULE lib = LoadLibrary(L"test.dll");

typedef std::string(*FNPTR)(std::string&, std::string&);
FNPTR myfunc = (FNPTR)GetProcAddress(lib, "pomnoz");

if (!myfunc)
    return 1;

std::string a("a");
std::string b("b");

myfunc(a, b);
```

Comment: Thanks ill try it,but will it collide with g++ so i need add something like ifdef visual?

Comment: Yes, you need: `#if defined(_MSC_VER)`